# Php Webpage crashes Every time I try to run Ldap_connect() Function

Tags: php, apache, server, xampp, ldap

I was trying to connect to Ldap Server using a simple Code. It is as follows,

```
<?php

// Ldap auth
$host = 'ldap.forumsys.com'; //CHANGE THIS TO THE CORRECT LDAP SERVER
$port = '389';
$password = "password";
$ds = ldap_connect($host, $port);
//echo $ds;


$dn = "read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com";

if ($bind = ldap_bind($ds, $dn, $password)) {
    echo ("Success");
    $pop = true;
} else {
    echo "Failed: Please check your username or passwordd";
    $pop = false;
}
```

However Each time I try to run this script the webpage crashes showing:
[image]

I checked the error Log in Xampp and I got this:

```
[Thu Mar 02 02:01:03.927881 2023] [core:notice] [pid 55570] AH00052: child pid 60282 exit signal Abort trap (6)
dyld[55568]: Assertion failed: (this->magic == kMagic), function loadAddress, file Loader.cpp, line 133.
```

I've tried enabling and disabling the ldap extension, tried reinstalling php, Upgrading php to 8.0.1 but nothing worked.I'm using MacOs Ventura 13.0.1.

Please Help me out.

Comment: This isn't a coding issue. Errors with dyld usually come from somewhere else. I'm seeing suggestions to upgrade Xcode, upgrade brew, but there doesn't seem to be a single fix

Comment: Thanks, I've tried updating brew, will try updating Xcode.